# cache memory and linking of two sites

Tags: caching

I have linked my drupal 7 website using xampp with php and hosted on hots gator. Where is the caching of memory happening?And how can i link the database of two sites, both made using drupal?

Comment: What do you mean by "I have linked my Drupal 7 website"? What have you linked it to and how?